# Displays and their relative position in a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, x11, xrandr

I want to get information about the displays, something like `xrandr`, but with more info.

I want to know their position. So if I have two or more displays connected I want to know how they are related to each other. If we are using the displays as an extending and not as a duplicate. With a shell command I want to know If I have any display to the left, right, up or down.

Is there something similar? Or at least a command where I give the id of the display and it tells me if I have another display in any direction?

Comment: The output of `xrandr` has all the information, “all” you need is to parse it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I have managed to understand the xrandr output, so I decided to answer my own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I couldn't test all the options, but it seems that `xrandr` has a **left** to **right** and **top** to **bottom** orientation.

Here's a screenshot of my monitors to help understand better:

[image: monitors layout]

When I run `xrandr` on my Terminal, this is what I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3046 x 1050, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+282 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0* 
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

Now on this output for me at first, there wasn't anything that could make me figure how they are related, but messing around with the Monitors layouts and after reading I find out how xrandr represents the relationships between Monitors.

If you notice my Monitors have different resolution screens and `xrandr`creates some sort of virtual resolution combining the **biggest** width with the biggest height.

That's why on the first line of my output I get that my current resolution is:

```
3046 x 1050 = (1366+1680) x 1050
```

We add both width resolutions and keep the biggest height.

This is because I have my Monitors layout side by side, if by any chance I change my Monitors layout to something like this:

[image: monitors layout 2]

The `xrandr` is this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1680 x 1818, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+314+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+0+768 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 473mm x 296mm
   1680x1050      60.0* 
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9
```

So as you may have noticed, the virtual resolution now is:

```
1680 x 1818 = 1680 x (768+1050)
```

Now returning to the first layout and `xrandr` output, my laptop resolution was this:

```
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+282
```

So what this means is that my laptop is as left as possible to the origin (my X is zero) and also has a 282px distance to the origin from the top (my Y is 282px or -282px, but lets assume 282px for the sake of simplicity):

[image: Monitors Layout]

And if I check the `xrandr` output for my other Monitor I get:

```
VGA1 connected 1680x1050+1366+0
```

**1366** is the width of my laptop Monitor, so I can assume that this display is on the right of my laptop Monitor.

Comment: Huge thanks for the math explanation and the valuable Figures with the red numbers!